# Using javascript to submit a post request to a server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a web crawler that can integrate with our partner portals and submit post requests to make bid changes.

The trouble is that the crawler runs in an environment which cannot execute `jQuery`, only native Javascript.

I have determined that the following `AJAX` code successfully sends the post request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://acp.example.com/campaigns/122828",
  data: "data-string"
});
```

Is there a way to translate the above statement into native javascript so that the crawler can execute it?

**UPDATE**

When executing hex494D49's native Javascript below, I am receiving a "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://acp.fyber.com/campaigns/122828" message.

However, when I execute the original AJAX code in firebug, it successfully sends the POST request.

Any idea why the same url would return a 404 error using native Javascript as opposed to AJAX?

Thanks

[image: Successful AJAX]

[image: 404 error with native Javascript]

Comment: jQuery IS pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

Sending AJAX request using POST method

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 var url = "url";
 var data = "email=hey@mail.com&password=101010";
 xhr.open("POST", url, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
         // do something with response
         console.log(xhr.responseText);
     }
};
xhr.send(data);
```

Sending AJAX request using GET method

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "url?email=hey@mail.com&password=101010";
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
         // do something with response
         console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

To avoid unexpected requests to the server, it's a good practice to use `encodeURIComponent()` method on any user-entered parameters that will be passed as part of a URI.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

I am receiving a 404 error when I try to execute that code in Firebug. Any idea why the same url would return a 404 error using native Javascript as opposed to AJAX?

Comment: @user2486308 Well, I just copy-pasted the url used on your snippet above. That url obviously doesn't exist (404 = Page not found). You should use your url and everything will work just fine.

Comment: I'm using the same url that I was originally using with the AJAX. Check out the screenshots I just attached - url is exactly the same, but one method generates a 404 error and the other does not. Any idea why?
Thank you

Comment: @user2486308 Another thing, you can't test this snippet from your browser (from your localhost) just like that to some public domain. This snippet and the target file should be hosted on the same domain. Or, you should put this line `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] . "");` in the file you're calling (from your localhost in this case). But, finally this `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` should be replaced with the domain allowed to access this file. Yes, it's complicated... :)

Comment: @user2486308 Have you found out what was the issue?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for following up. Unfortunately I am still a bit confused. I understand the components of the AJAX request, but not the native Javascript you posted. Specifically, your reference to a "target file." I simply want to send the data in the "data-string" to the server. There is no file involved in the AJAX request, so I'm not sure what file is being involved in the Javascript request. I'm also unconcerned with any response from the server, as long as the data in the "data-string" is effectively Posted (i.e., the bid is successfully updated).

Can you clarify what this "target file" is?

Comment: @user2486308 I updated my answer so you can see how to send a request using both GET and POST method. There's no other way to make an AJAX request with JavaScript and that's the main reason why this question has no other answers. I believe that there's something else causing your issue. If you share some data you're sending to the server I could test this in more details.